Validate request signature and sign response in SOAP services with spring-ws
Premise: I need to create a SOAP service that uses the WS-Security standard to do what's described in the title, so that a SOAP client can consume this service.
What do I have

Soap service done with java 17 + spring boot 3.3.3
the .cer that my client uses to sign request
the .cer and .key of my own certificate
a .p12 file and a .jks file generated with commands from chatgpt

Basically, it involves sending the certificate (.cer file) in the soap:Header of the envelope that's sent/received. However, I've encountered several difficulties in achieving this. Based on what I've seen, I only have two options:

Use WS-Security from Spring Boot with a class called Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.
Capture the outgoing SOAP message in a SoapEndpointInterceptor and add the relevant fields.

Neither of these approaches has worked for me.
Scenario 1:
After many questions and fine-tuning with my chat-gpt/gemini, all I get is code with made-up methods or ones that don't do what I need. I read the library's documentation, and the methods don't explain where to retrieve values from or how to calculate them.
So, I resort to trial and error, following the available info. I pass a crypto.properties file along with a .p12 file that contains my .cer and .key with valid password and alias. I've also tried with a .jks file, but in both cases, I get errors like "unrecognized character 111" or that the library wasn't initialized properly.
Overall, I try all the methods from the class using both p12 and jks formats, along with the crypto.properties file, but the service either doesn't start or fails to sign, instead sending a 202 response with an empty body to my endpoint.
Result? The service doesn't even start because of the aforementioned errores.
Scenario 2:
Using this and that to the letter, I create all the necessary tags.

BinarySecurityToken: I put the .cer converted to base64 using the X.509Certificate class.
DigestMethod and SignatureMethod use SHA-1 and SHA-1withRSA, respectively.
DigestValue: A SHA-1 hash generated from the raw XML content as a string from the soap:Body (it doesn't include the body itself, only the root element inside it).
SignatureValue: Using Java's Signer class, I extract the private key from the .p12 file generated from my original .cer and .key (the same .cer used in the BinarySecurityToken), and I sign the raw XML string of the SignedInfo element (including itself and all its content).

If you look at the two references I'm using, you'll notice that some attributes like ID need to be considered, right?

Reference (inside the SecurityTokenReference) has a URI attribute that points to the wsu:Id attribute in the BinarySecurityToken (this is a UUID I generate myself).
Reference (outside the SecurityTokenReference), based on examples I found online, has a URI attribute that points to the wsu:id attribute present in the soap:Body. I generate this with a UUID as well.
Timestamp: I just set the current time, with an expiration one hour ahead.

Result? When the client validates my response, they get a "signature is invalid" exception. I tried with self-signed certificates, CA-issued certificates, and certificates without special characters, but none of these variations changed the outcome. We also verified that the .cer on their side matches the one I'm using.
Notes:

No, a REST service is not an option.
No, not using this standard is not an option; it has to be done this way.
It has to be done in Java 17 + Spring Boot 3+.

Edit 1
Additional notes:

I also have to do it the other way around (the service will consume another soap service. I have to sign the request and validate the signature of the response).
I have to add a few custom xml elements to the <soap:Header>

closest thing to work, my client still cannot read it but the service starts, I have no idea if I am doing correctly

@Configuration
@EnableWs
public class SoapService extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    
    // other soap-service-related beans like message dispatcher, marshaller, and so on.
    
    @Bean
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() {
        Wss4jSecurityInterceptor interceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
        
        try {
            // check incoming certificate, this does produce an output similar to the ones on my cites, but not equal
            interceptor.setSecurementActions(WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE);
            interceptor.setValidationCallbackHandler(this.securityCallback());
            
            // sign outgoing response
            interceptor.setSecurementActions(WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE);
            interceptor.setSecurementUsername("your_alias");
            interceptor.setSecurementPassword("your_password");
            interceptor.setSecurementSignatureCrypto(this.cryptoConfig().getObject());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("error while initializing interceptor");
        }
        
        return interceptor;
    }
    
    @Bean
    CryptoFactoryBean cryptoConfig() throws IOException {
        CryptoFactoryBean bean = new CryptoFactoryBean();
        bean.setKeyStorePassword("your_password");
        bean.setKeyStoreLocation(new ClassPathResource("certificate.jks"));
        return bean;
    }
    
    @Bean
    CallbackHandler securityCallback() {
        // how am i supposed to check the .cer my client sends here?
        return new SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler() {{
            setUsers(new Properties() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 3422928594124631515L;

                {
                    setProperty("alias", "your_password");
                }
            });
        }};
    }
    
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        interceptors.add(securityInterceptor());
    }
    
}


Don't mess around with creating elements yourself, the Wss4jSecurityInterceptor. Please show the configuration you had.

@M.Deinum I edited the question as requested with the information mentioned.
